# Pass 2d array in function - return 2d array from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, 2d

So i have read the other threads but i cant figure it out. My code is the following and it works fine.

```
double **sort(int counter, double **a){
    int i, j;
    double swap0, swap1;

    for (i = 0 ; i < ( counter - 1 ); i++){
        for (j = 0 ; j < counter - i - 1; j++){
            if (a[0][j] > a[0][j+1]){
                swap0 = a[0][j];
                swap1 = a[1][j];
                a[0][j] = a[0][j+1];
                a[1][j] = a[1][j+1];
                a[0][j+1] = swap0;
                a[1][j+1] = swap1;
            }
        }
    }

    return a;
}

main(){

    double **dist_table;
    int i;

    dist_table = (double **)calloc(2,sizeof(double*));
    dist_table[0] = (double *)calloc(5,sizeof(double));
    dist_table[1] = (double *)calloc(5,sizeof(double));

    dist_table[0][0] = 5.1;
    dist_table[1][0] = 0;
    dist_table[0][1] = 6.1;
    dist_table[1][1] = 1;
    dist_table[0][2] = 3.1;
    dist_table[1][2] = 2;
    dist_table[0][3] = 2.1;
    dist_table[1][3] = 3;
    dist_table[0][4] = 7.1;
    dist_table[1][4] = 4;

    dist_table = sort(5, dist_table);
}
```

BUT i read that passing as an argument the **a is wrong. So why my codes runs fine, and which would be the right way?

Comment: Can you point out that source where you read that argument?

Comment: @DhavalKapil http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9a.html   i know that this is too old, but in the end it says this argument is wrong

Comment: @user3143155: That page is talking about multidimensional arrays, which is not what you have here. What you have here is a one-dimensional (dynamically allocated) array of pointers, each element of which points to another one-dimensional (dynamically allocated) array of `double`s. Actual multi-dimensional arrays are represented differently in memory to this, which is exactly why the linked page says not to confuse them.

Comment: Yeah @PaulGriffiths is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is just returning the same pointer you passed to it. Replacing:

```
dist_table = sort(5, distortable);
```

with:

```
sort(5, distortable);
```

would generally be better in this case, although sometimes returning the same value can be useful (e.g. if you want to use it within a larger expression).

For the last part of your question, passing a `double **` would be wrong if you actually had a two-dimensional array of `double`s, like this:

```
double my_array[2][5];
```

but that isn't what you have. You have a one-dimensional (dynamically allocated) array of `double *`, each element of which points to a one-dimensional (dynamically allocated) array of `double`. Actual multi-dimensional arrays are represented differently in memory to this, which is why passing a `double **` would not work. But what you actually have here is completely different, and passing a `double **` is fine, here.

Other unrelated points...

Casting the return from `calloc()` is completely unnecessary, and generally considered bad form. Better would be:

```
dist_table = calloc(2,sizeof(double*));
dist_table[0] = calloc(5,sizeof(double));
dist_table[1] = calloc(5,sizeof(double));
```

or better still:

```
dist_table =  calloc(2,sizeof *dist_table);
for ( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
    dist_table[i] = calloc(5,sizeof *(dist_table[i]));
}
```

Don't forget to check the return value of `calloc()` to find out if the allocation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the depth of the array and elements size you're doing it the right way.

Consider null terminating the array if the number of elements are dynamic and not limited to two.